# XML to Pandas dataFrame returns None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm beginning with data science and pandas, I'm trying to populate a pandas dataframe with XML infos here is my code :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
import sys

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    parsed_xml = et.parse("test2.xml")
    dfcols = ['Country','Club', 'Founded']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        Country = node.attrib.get('country')
        Club = node.find('Name')
        Founded = node.find('Founded')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([Country, getvalueofnode(Club),getvalueofnode(Founded)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    print(df_xml)

main()
```

Here is my output :

> Country  Club Founded
>
> 0    None  None    None

Here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SoccerFeed timestamp="20181123T153249+0000">
  <SoccerDocument Type="SQUADS Latest" competition_code="FR_L1" competition_id="24" competition_name="French Ligue 1" season_id="2016" season_name="Season 2016/2017">
    <Team country="France" country_id="8" country_iso="FR" region_id="17" region_name="Europe" >
      <Founded>1919</Founded>
      <Name>Angers</Name>
   <...>
   <Team country="France" country_id="8" country_iso="FR" region_id="17" region_name="Europe" >
      <Founded>1905</Founded>
      <Name>Bastia</Name>
```

Why can't I get a Panda Data Frame with the informations I need ? Did I miss something in my code ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you share a valid xml as I get an error when trying to parse through the XML DOM with your code?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by adding the closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML, `<Founded>` and `<Name>` are child tags for the `<Team>` tag and the `country` attribute is also part of the `<Team>` tag. Hence, we should `iter`ate over the XML DOM of the `<Team>` tag. Next, there should be some way to store the values of the `for` loop on each iteration as these would be the row values for each column. We can do this by creating a dictionary(`df_dict`) of the three columns with their values set to empty lists. We append the corresponding lists for each `Country`, `Club` and `Founded` on each iteration. Finally, we create the Dataframe(`df`) from this dictionary.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

def main():
    parsed_xml = et.parse("test.xml")
    df_dict = {'Country':[],'Club':[], 'Founded':[]}    
    root = parsed_xml.getroot()
    for country in root.iter('Team'):
        Country = country.attrib.get('country')
        Club = country.find('Name').text
        Founded = country.find('Founded').text 
        df_dict['Country'].append(Country)
        df_dict['Club'].append(Club)
        df_dict['Founded'].append(Founded) 

    print('Dict for dataframe: {}'.format(df_dict))
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
    print("Dataframe: \n{}".format(df))

main()
```

The following is the Output on running this script:

```
#Output:
Dict for dataframe: {'Country': ['France', 'France'], 'Club': ['Angers', 'Bastia'], 'Founded': ['1919', '1905']}
Dataframe:
  Country    Club Founded
0  France  Angers    1919
1  France  Bastia    1905
```