# Access data in XML tag with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm beginnning with data analysis, I want to parse an XML file in order to analyze data, Here is a portion of my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SoccerFeed>
  <SoccerDocument>
    <Team>
      <Founded>1919</Founded>
      <Name>Angers</Name>
      <Player uID="p40511">
        <Name>Denis Petric</Name>
        <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
        <Stat Type="first_name">Denis</Stat>
        <Stat Type="last_name">Petric</Stat>
        <Stat Type="preferred_foot">Left</Stat>
      </Player>
      <Player uID="p119744">
        <Name>Mathieu Michel</Name>
        <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
        <Stat Type="first_name">Mathieu</Stat>
        <Stat Type="preferred_foot">Right</Stat>
      </Player>
    </Team>
  </SoccerDocument>
</SoccerFeed>
```

How can I access to the preferred_foot in Stat tag ? Here is my python code to access these data :

```
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
teams = dom.findall('SoccerDocument/Team')
for t in teams:
    team_name = t.find('Name').text
    founded = t.find('Founded').text
    players = t.findall('Player')
    for pl in players:
        player_name = pl.find('Name').text
        player_position = pl.find('Position').text
        preferred_foot = pl.find('Stat[@Type="preferred_foot"]')
```

Comment: @userHG, I think I answered a similar question yesterday. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200435/xml-to-pandas-dataframe-returns-none

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to Pandas dataFrame returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200435/xml-to-pandas-dataframe-returns-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

The idea is to find all Stat elements where Type is prefered_foot

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SoccerFeed>
  <SoccerDocument>
    <Team>
      <Founded>1919</Founded>
      <Name>Angers</Name>
      <Player uID="p40511">
        <Name>Denis Petric</Name>
        <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
        <Stat Type="first_name">Denis</Stat>
        <Stat Type="last_name">Petric</Stat>
        <Stat Type="preferred_foot">Left</Stat>
      </Player>
      <Player uID="p119744">
        <Name>Mathieu Michel</Name>
        <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
        <Stat Type="first_name">Mathieu</Stat>
        <Stat Type="preferred_foot">Right</Stat>
      </Player>
    </Team>
  </SoccerDocument>
</SoccerFeed>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
prefered_foots = root.findall(".//Stat[@Type='preferred_foot']")
for foot in prefered_foots:
    print(foot.text)
```

Output

```
Left
Right
```